# Which color codes are used?

Tags: css, colors

I wonder which colors are being used by this [website](http://osomstudio.com/en/)?
The website uses a different colors for each layout. They look really good, but I am not able to identify which color codes are exactly used.

For greenish one, I could come most closer to this #6db286

Can some help me identify do that, also how to identify in general the color code used by seeing a website?

what is proper way to do that..or is it just a hit and trial?

Comment: This is not a question for Stack Overflow. However, it should help you that Firefox has a color picker in the developer tools. I don't know if Chrome has that, too, but even if not there must be lots of addons for that.

Comment: Google for "X color picker" or "X eyedropper" where X is either the name of your browser or the name of your operating system.

Comment: you can use tools for that, extensions such as colorzilla.

Comment: This is not a site for *please go to this other site and see how they're doing this thing, and then come back and explain it to me* posts.

Comment: @everyone the tools which you guys are suggesting, are more of hit and trial. I was as well using `http://www.color-hex.com/`, but surely that's a time investing effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that

```
https://zedbi.azurewebsites.net/View-a-websites-color-scheme
```

There you can get the color scheme of a website

Comment: Thanks i was looking for this exactly